# Magento - cart not showing and checkout/cart page empty (doesn't show the .cart div)

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

Okay, so I'm a newbie to Magento and have been making lots of changes to get it working the way a client is wanting.

Obviously at install and early on, the shopping cart was working fine.  I moved it up to the top right corner for a while w/ CSS and then I THOUGHT that I display:none'd it, as I just wanted to focus on other things for a while before moving on to styling it.  Now I've done all those other things and want to deal with the cart.  Trouble is - it is nowhere to be found and the display:none that I thought I'd used to turn it off is similarly missing.  Maybe I never did it?

I can't find anything in the CSS that would have turned off the cart - I can't find a display:none on it or any parents.  Most of the site is using a 2 column with left sidebar layout, and I know the shopping cart resides by default in the right.  But when I turn back on the right sidebar - no cart.  Furthermore, when I go to add a product to the cart, I am redirected to mydomain.com/checkout/cart as expected, but there is nothing on the page.  My styling, menus, etc are present but the .col-main element where the full-page detailed cart should be is empty.  Which makes me think again that the problem isn't CSS.

It's as if the site just isn't calling for the cart (I assume cart.phtml?).  It is totally possible that I screwed something up while messing with other things (adding a CMS page menu at top, lots to do with resizing images, moving the category menu to the left sidebar). My php isn't good enough to find the culprit and I'm not even sure which file I should be looking at - checkout.phtml?

I realize this question has very little valuable information, but does anyone have any ideas as to where I should be looking?  I can post the relevant code if I know which file to look in.  The site is cart.oldfloridian.com.  If you want to try to add a product, there is only one at the moment, at "ak starfish --> starfish women's"

Edit: so the /checkout/cart page is a 3column layout.  Here is the 3columns.phtml code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<div id="cms-menu">
    <?php $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());?>
    <?php  $collection->getSelect()
          ->where('is_active = 1'); ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($collection as $page): ?>
      <?php $PageData = $page->getData(); ?>
      <?php if($PageData['identifier']!='no-route') { ?>
      <li>
        <a href="/<?php echo $PageData['identifier']?>"><?php echo $PageData['title'] ?></a>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col3-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I would start by doing is enabling 'Template Path Hints' in the Magento admin backend. You'll be able to see which blocks and templates reside where. I'm also trying to add a product to the cart but I get a white screen when I try to do so.

Comment: @okcorez - Awesome.  Thanks for the tip.  So I have the hints on now and on the cart page (www.cart.oldfloridian.com/checkout/cart/) we see that the page is 3columns.phtml (I think it is the only one still on this layout).  And the only thing in the main column is 
"frontend/default/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml," which incidentally has an inline style "display:none," though changing this didn't seem to have any effect...  Not sure what the popup is.

Comment: Well I couldn't figure this one out so I backed everything up, reinstalled Magento and just reuploaded the files I'd changed bit by bit while keeping an eye on things.  Now my site is back to where I want it and has the cart.  I never did find the problem.  I guess whatever I did to screw it up wasn't a change I needed...

Comment: Sometimes that's all you can do. Perhaps you could commit your code to version control (Git?) and keep committing changes so you can rollback if needed.

Answer (score 2):

There does seem to be a bug in there somewhere - we had a similar issue where two devs in the team couldnt see the cart, 1 could - but it wasnt just the cart it was the whole customer section (login, cart, my account etc).

We tried enabling Template Path Hints but the only thing in the main section of the page was "frontend/default/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml". We re-installed most of magento - no luck

We tried pretty much everything and what fixed it was coping all of the theme files into a new theme and re-naming it. Only thing I can think of that it could have been was a hyphen in the theme name

Comment: me too. I can see the block is firing but the cart.phtml mentioned in layout never gets fired. I wish there was a better debug to show what is trying to override it.